# Multiple select using listpicker in windowsphone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7

SelectionMode property is not found in ListPicker.We included reference to Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit in our project and also included

xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

in the xaml page.But we are not able to give SelectionMode=Multiple

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version, previous versions didn't have a `SelectionMode` property